# MulterError: Unexpected field

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, multer

tengo un proyecto para cargar videos, imágenes y su posterior almacenamiento de una base de datos NoSQL (MongoDB), pero cuando inicializo multer me da un error: MulterError: Unexpected Ahora voy a mostrarle el código en caso de que pueda ayúdame, te lo agradecería

El código:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const engine = require('ejs-mate');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const multer = require('multer');

// initializations
const app = express();
require('./database');

// settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3002);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(multer({dest: path.join(__dirname, '../src/public/upload/temp')}).single('image'));
app.use(multer({dest: path.join(__dirname, '../src/public/upload/video')}).single('video'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));

// Starting the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('server on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Este es el código donde tengo un multer y su configuración para recibir imágenes y videos, pero los videos no me permiten subirlos.
Una vez más, agradecería que me dieras una solución a este problema.

Gracias.

Comment: Estas en SO en Español, traduce tu pregunta.

Comment: Sorry bro que siempre me dicen que lo escriba en ingles

Comment: podrias poner el error entero o solo es eso?

Comment: es solo eso no es nada mas